# open menu on click instead of hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am unable to open my menu on click event. It opens on mouse hover event. I know it is a very simple question. I tried but am unable to resolve it. I need this for automation using selenium because it does not capture mouse hover events.

you can view my code on 
https://jsfiddle.net/ansari4all/ssyor80k/

```
<div align="center" class="action_dropdown_container">
    <ul class="action_dropdown">
        <li>
            <a href="">Action</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="abc.php">Edit</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="xyz.php">View</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```css
ul.action_dropdown {
    font-family: "titilliumtext22l_ltmedium", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
}
ul.action_dropdown li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
ul.action_dropdown li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul.action_dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    background:#fff url(../../images/xadmin/action_dropdown_arrow.png) no-repeat 42px 6px;
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    line-height:19px;
    height:19px;
    padding:0px 12px 0px 5px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.action_dropdown_container {
    width:55px; 
    height:21px;
}
.alignmiddle {
    vertical-align:middle !important;
}
ul.action_dropdown li a:hover {
}
ul.action_dropdown li ul li a {
    background:#329ac4 !important;
    color:#fff;
}
ul.action_dropdown li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:999;
    right: 0px;
    /*top: -75px;*/
}
ul.action_dropdown li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-top:-1px;
}
```

Comment: for that case you have to use js.

Comment: i dont think we have to use js, i am sure that it is possible using css

Comment: If you are sure then try something and if you stuck somewhere then state the exact issue.

Comment: i am very close i have used :active instead of :hover , using this problem is resolved but page is getting refreshed

Comment: @JunedAnsari active wont help you as active will work while you are in click mode. As you remove click it will not work. and page is refreshed because of you are using link in a href.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is to play with Ul li and child css. The ul is not the child of anchor tag so you need to use + to get the next sibling of the anchor tag.

Please add this css in your code

```
ul.action_dropdown li > a:focus + ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:999;
    right: 0px;
    /*top: -75px;*/
}
ul.action_dropdown li > a:focus + ul li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-top:-1px;
}
```

See in [action](https://jsfiddle.net/u4t2yw9s/3/)

Comment: but using this page is getting refreshed

Comment: Check in my fiddle. Its not refreshing. Use javascript:(); instead of # in your anchor tag's href link

Answer (score -1):

For clickevents you could use jQuery in your page. For loading jquery check google or SO, but after making sure you are loading jQuery before this you could do something like:

JQuery:

```
//start on dom ready
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
//hook on the click event of desired element 
 jQuery('.dropdown').click(function(){
// toggle is-visible class or something..
 jQuery('.action_dropdown').toggleClass('is-visible');
});
});
```

CSS:

```
 .dropdown { display:none }
 .is-visible {display:block}
```

Comment: jQuery is not needed. You can do this also with plain Javascript.

Comment: I mentioned it because you wrote: "you will need to use jQuery" which is not true. It should be "you could use" e.g.

Comment: Edited :) Martin Cup

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
<div align="center" class="action_dropdown_container" onClick="myfunction()"></div>
```

The only thing you now have to do is change the function name and Voila!